# Python OrderdDict values() function saves the order?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Does orderedDict.values(), .keys(), .iterkeys() etc. returns the values in the order that items were first inserted?

I assume that values\keys function does not change the order of the dict, and if it's orderedDict, then i get the values in the order that they were added to the dictionary.

That's true?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. `OrderedDict` maintains a list of (thus ordered) keys to iterate over values and keys, so they will always be ordered the same way as in `for` loops.

The comments in the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e961a166dc70/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l26) also states this, saying:

> The inherited dict provides `__getitem__`, `__len__`, `__contains__`, and `get`. **The remaining methods are order-aware.** Big-O running times for all methods are the same as regular dictionaries.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

> Does orderedDict.values(), .keys(), .iterkeys() etc. returns the values in the order that items were first inserted?

Yes, they are preserved. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Equality tests between OrderedDict objects are order-sensitive and are
>   implemented as **list(od1.items())==list(od2.items()).**

Thats how equality comparison is done, and it implies that the result of `items()` are ordered. Now for other two functions you can look into a [substitute implementation for OrderedDict here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/)